# Log Analytics query - group string/object

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql

i have a query that show me the result of 5xx and 4xx errors in the last 5 minutes:

```
    requests
| where timestamp > now() - 5m
| where url contains "xxxxxx" and resultCode startswith "5" or resultCode startswith "4"
| project resultCode
| summarize Count= count() by resultCode
```

query print me all 5xx and 4xx as following:

[image]

is possible to get the count of all 4xx and 5xx but printed in 2 row??
Example:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick

[run in web](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02OywqDMBBF937FxY0GZmHQ%20oKuuuwniAs1QQSNYBKwpR/fpFZwZjOH4V6O6IzbfpbxJrWdzWMVsoY226RGwrBaZWrMqxoZGgRwkyUJoSroD5xQ5NlJKSHnvDwxc8%20kTE/MCZwfcPMtPOVBG3wgdyOVwGHwnJS4e4OhM7G2/eFy0SP4KCOE%20x4yF9d2Wbptekt/xU30s45ahv516fwCLhsbmOoAAAA=)

```
datatable(resultCode: string, count: long) [ 
    400, 97,
    401, 764,
    403, 6118,
    404, 7083,
    406, 11,
    500, 131
]
| extend resultKind= strcat(substring(resultCode, 0, 1), "xx")
| summarize sum(['count']) by resultKind
```

Comment: Hi Rony, thanks. I inserted "| extend resultKind= strcat(substring(resultCode, 0, 1), "xx")
| summarize sum(['count']) by resultKind" after "| project resultCode"  but i got "'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named '["count"]'" . I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: you need to do it after your summarize and then use `Count` instead of `['count']`